# Python datetime strptime parsing error, why is two hours between '2008-10-26 01:00:00' and '2008-10-26 00:00:00'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, python-datetime

I'm manipulating timedates and I've found something strange:
I've just created a simple function to transform dates into datetimes (in seconds) and I've found this:

```
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> parsefunc = lambda date : time.mktime(datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timetuple())
>>> parsefunc('2008-10-25 01:00:00')-parsefunc('2008-10-25 00:00:00')
3600.0
```

All ok, there is 3600 s in one hour.

```
>>> parsefunc('2008-10-26 01:00:00')-parsefunc('2008-10-26 00:00:00')
7200.0
```

But here there is 7200 s of difference.

Does anyone know what is happening? Is any library deprecated? I've found some other dates when there is the same problem:
'2009-10-25 00:00:00', '2010-10-31 00:00:00', '2011-10-30 00:00:00', '2012-10-28 00:00:00', '2013-10-27 00:00:00', '2014-10-26 00:00:00', '2015-10-25 00:00:00', '2016-10-30 00:00:00', '2017-10-29 00:00:00' and '2018-10-28 00:00:00'

Thanks in advance, I can avoid this problem but I'm curious why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just found why is this happening, it's just the time change :)